# AlarmManager not triggering AlarmNotificationReceiver

Tags: java, android

I am building a gym app that let the user pick the difficulties. The difficulties set according to the time and after the users check the difficulties and click the gym postures. Time will running according to the difficulties and if time run's up, alarm would be triggered. But in my condtion, the alarm would not triggered after the time run's out. I already add the  receiver android:name at manifest. Here is my code:

```
 private void saveAlarm(boolean checked) {

    if (checked) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        int Hour, Minute;

        alarmIntent = new Intent(Setting.this, AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            Hour = timePicker.getHour();
            Minute = timePicker.getMinute();

        } else {

            Minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            Hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
        }

        Date dat = new Date();
        Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_now.setTime(dat);
        cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hour);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minute);
        cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        if (cal_alarm.before(cal_now)) {
            cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmNotificationReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("It's time")
            .setContentText("Time to training")
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your receiver like this in AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.AlarmNotificationReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.AlarmNotificationReceiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Set your intent like this and set Alarm like this:

```java
Intent intent = Intent();
intent.setClass(context,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("com.example.AlarmNotificationReceiver");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

`setExact` is called on the exact time it is set.

Notice that from Android Oreo, notifications need notification channels to be displayed.

Create Notification channel like this:

```java
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default","Default",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Create Notification like this:

```java
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        .setContentTitle("It's time")
        .setContentText("Time to training")
        .setContentInfo("Info")
        .build();
manager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks man ! It works. I found out the problem was mainly due to Oreo notification channel. I testing it with my phone which is API 28, that why I unable to receive the notifcation.

Comment: @LiewSyetChau Welcome :) Don't forgert to upvote answer if it solves your problem. It helps me and other developers also.